# jquery ajax return duplicate result (twice)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jquery ajax to catch form vars > send them to PHP > get result > update IFRAME.

But from some reason I'm getting the result twice, for example the PHP should return: 
"hello world"

But I'm getting: "hello worldhello world"

```
$('#PurchaseForm').submit(function() {
    var serializedData = $("#PurchaseForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkout.php",
        data: serializedData
        }).done(function( result ) {
            alert(result);
            var $iframe = $('#plimus');
            if ( $iframe.length ) {
                $iframe.attr('src',result);   
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Thanks
Shai

Comment: How many times your request is sending.?one or two?Also check your browser console and post your php code

Comment: Could it be a php-side problem ?